# I need help in decoding this output . I have used python file operations .Can anyone tell why I am getting this output

Tags: python-2.7

This is **input file** given by me contents of file.txt

```
THIS IS A

THIS IS B

THIS IS C

THIS IS D

THIS IS E

THIS IS F
```

This is the **output I am getting** (contents of file2.txt)

```
THIS IS A

THATTTTTTTTTTIS IS C

THIS IS D

THIS IS E

THIS IS F
```

The below lines are the **output which I was expecting**

```
THIS IS A

THATTTTTTTTTT

THIS IS C

THIS IS D

THIS IS E

THIS IS F
```

**My code :**

```
import os
import sys
with open("file.txt","r") as rf:
    with open("file2.txt","w") as wf:
        while True:
            curr_line=rf.tell()
            line=rf.readline()
            if "B" in line:
                cg_pos=curr_line
            if "E" in line:
                e_pos=curr_line
                wf.seek(cg_pos)
                wf.write("THATTTTTTTTTT")
                wf.seek(0,2)
            wf.write(line)
            if not line:
                break
```

Comment: what is your output

Comment: I have edited my question and added output thanks.